# Capybara::ElementNotFound: Unable to find field "Key name"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, capybara

I've read the similar questions to this but they don't solve my issue. I'm new with js testing so I think I might be doing something wrong.

The form produces this HTML

```
<form class="new_category_item_key" id="new_category_item_key" action="/guides/dungeon-boss/categories?category_id=heroes" accept-charset="UTF-8" data-remote="true" method="post"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /><input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="b7wiF07zYh/Nl727M3y0Uk1TbroMJFuGqTK6fYNlNted/5G4Wmz4BZLb7IazzyP5md/wWRb1D28ePhrzt2uMSA==" />


   <label for="category_item_key_name">Key name</label>
   <input type="text" name="category_item_key[name]" id="category_item_key_name" />

<select name="category_item_key[key_type]" id="category_item_key_key_type"><option value="1">Value</option>
<option value="2">Text</option>
<option value="3">Image</option></select>

   <input type="submit" name="commit" value="Add New Key" />
</form>
```

and I have the following integration test on the form

```
setup do
    @user = users(:michael)
    @user1 = users(:archer)
    @guide = Guide.find(1)
    @mod_relationship = game_mods_relationships(:mod1)
    @category = Category.find(1)
    Capybara.current_driver = Capybara.javascript_driver # :selenium by default
  end

test "adding keys mod success then fail" do
  log_in_as(@user)
  get edit_guide_category_path(@guide, @category)
  assert_template 'categories/edit'
  assert_difference 'CategoryItemKey.count', 1 do
  fill_in 'Key name', with: "diablo"
  click_button "commit"
  end

end
```

when I run the test I get the following error

`Capybara::ElementNotFound:         Capybara::ElementNotFound: Unable to find field "Key name"`

Looking at the HTML I can see the field is there. If I try using the inputs `id` it still fails, if I remove the fill in line then it says it cant find the button to click which is also there. I assume its getting the right page because `get edit_guide_category_path(@guide, @category)` works for the other tests (but they are non js tests and don't use selenium).

Its probably something simple but I cant get it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're mixing up two different libraries -- You can't use `get` with Capybara, you use `visit(url)` to go to the page.  You also shouldn't normally be asserting templates in a feature test, thats for lower level tests.

Comment: Thanks that worked. Also what should I use instead of assert template? I want to make site the right page is loaded

Comment: In feature tests you check the content of the page  - `assert_text('some text content on the page')`  etc

Comment: Great. Thanks for the tip

Comment: `assert_text` doesn't work `undefined method `assert_text'` is that also because of the 2 different libraries problem?

Comment: assert_text should be there as long as you've included Capybara::DSL into whatever test class you're using which it would look like you have since you can call visit, fill_in and click_button -- Are you using a really old Capybara for some reason??  assert_text was added back in 2014 - the 2.4 versions

Comment: Eh for some reason I have 2.3, Updated it and it works. But I get a DB error problem now. I posted it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35375848/capybara-error-activerecordstatementinvalid-sqlite3busyexception-database. Would appreciate if you had a look :)