# Capybara error ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::BusyException: database is locked

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, capybara

I'm testing javascript and I get the following error when I try and submit data to the DB over an ajax form.

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid:         ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::BusyException: database is locked: INSERT INTO "check_category_item_keys" ("name", "key_type", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)
```

Here is my integration test file

```
require 'test_helper'

class JavascriptTestingTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest

setup do
    @user = users(:michael)
    @user1 = users(:archer)
    @guide = Guide.find(1)
    @mod_relationship = game_mods_relationships(:mod1)
    @category = Category.find(1)
    Capybara.current_driver = Capybara.javascript_driver # :selenium by default
  end


test "adding keys mod success then fail" do
  log_in_as(@user)
  visit(edit_guide_category_path(@guide, @category))
  itemkeycount = CategoryItemKey.count
  fill_in 'Key name', with: "diablo"
  click_button "Add New Key"  #works fine when this line is removed
end
```

I'm new to testing JS so I'm guessing there is something more I need to do or something I need to change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`#click_button` does not wait for the results of clicking the button to happen since it has no clue what those will be.  So in this case `#click_button` returns immediately, the test ends, and whatever you're using to clean the database between tests (DatabaseCleaner??) starts cleaning the database.  During that time the request triggered by click_button starts to get processed but the cleaning thread has already locked the database (or the other way around) so you get an error.  The solution is to have a line that waits for a visible side effect of whatever clicking the button does.

```
fill_in 'Key name', with: "diablo"
click_button "Add New Key"
assert_text "New Key Added!" # or whatever shows up the page
```

The assert_text will wait (up to a limit) for that text to appear which should mean the database is no longer in use, the test can finish and cleanup can happen.  The other thing to watch for is that you're NOT using transaction based testing since that will also cause you all sorts of issues when doing testing with a JS capable driver - see https://github.com/DatabaseCleaner/database_cleaner#what-strategy-is-fastest

Comment: I have `assert_text 'diablo'` just after `click_button` the text diablo is added to a div that is refreshed using ajax to display the newly added key(refreshed after form submit), I think I need to extend the limit for the text to appear.

Comment: If the assert_text isn't raising an error then you don't need to extend the time since it's seeing the text.  It's not clear from your description, is the text 'diablo' added to the div before the ajax call, or only on completion of the ajax call.  If the former (or if there are other instances of 'diablo' already on the page) then it's not a good change to be checking for.

Comment: You need to check for something that indicates the ajax has completed (and hence database access has completed too) - For instance if the ajax adds a div with class 'key' and you know there were 2 on the screen previously you could do  `assert_selector 'div.key', count: 3`  which would wait for there to be 3 'key' divs on the page - If you need more info - update your question to have the full test you're using and maybe add some of the html

Comment: I can have a check to see if the divs length has changed, but I don't know how to get the divs length (content in the div).

Comment: Or after the button click test tell it to wait 1 or 2 seconds (more than enough time)